# Firefox extension share async function with return gives => Error: Permission denied to access property "then"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

i'm trying to call an async function defined in my extension from a webpage and print the returned value of this function, but i get `"Error: Permission denied to access property "then""` (if i do it with a non async function i still get a Permission denied error).

My extension :

```
let ethereum = new window.Object(); 

let request = async function () {
    console.log("request");
    return ["0x00"]; }

exportFunction(request, ethereum, {
    defineAs: "request"   });    

window.wrappedJSObject.ethereum = ethereum;
```

My webpage :

```
const address = await ethereum.request();
```

The `console.log("request")` works.

I think I need to Wrap the returned variable or something but can't find what....

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exportFunction` won't work because your JS function is internally wired to the content script's `Promise` (this is what `async` does under the hood) and its prototypes (used to create its returned instance of `Promise`), which aren't auto-exported as they are not a part of the function.

- Use `eval` or `new Function` in the context of the page if the site's CSP allows `unsafe-eval`.

  ```js
  wrappedJSObject.eval(`test = ${async () => {
    console.log("request");
    return ["0x00"];
  }}`);
  ```

  or

  ```js
  wrappedJSObject.test = new wrappedJSObject.Function(`return (${async () => {
    console.log("request");
    return ["0x00"];
  }})()`);
  ```
- Use a `script` element if the site's CSP allows, [example](/a/9517879).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i find it hard to find extensive documention apart from the official one.